# Div not floating over other div

Tags: html, css

I have two div that I have floating. One is a background. The other is some text.

I am wanting the text to float over the background image that I have placed. I have gotten it working with all my other backgrounds before this, but for this specifically it seems to just push the content down below it randomly and cause my footer to float next to it.

Here is a fiddle so you can get an idea: http://jsfiddle.net/d78sdjm4/2/

The green (.contact_text) is supposed to be in the centre or at least on top of the red div (.mebg).
Then the black (.footer) is supposed to be positioned directly beneath the two.

HTML:

```
<div class="contactwrapper">
    <div class="contact">
     <p>please work</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mebg">
        <img src="images/contactnew.png" />
    </div>
</div>
<!-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------end of contact------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
<div class="footer">
<img src="images/footer.png" width="239" height="15" /> 
</div><!-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------end of footer------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

CSS:

```
.contactwrapper{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.contact{
    float:left;
    background:#0F3;
}
.mebg{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:#900;
}
mebg img{
    width:30%;
}
.footer{
    z-index: 1;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rphsjt1q/1/

```css
.contactwrapper{
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
}
.contact{
 position:absolute;
 background:#0F3;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:1;
    
}
.mebg{
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 background:#900;
    height:200px;
}
mebg img{
 width:30%;
}
.footer{
 z-index: 1;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: #000;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="contactwrapper">
    <div class="contact">
     <p>please work</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mebg">
     <img src="images/contactnew.png" />
    </div>
</div>
<!-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------end of contact------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
<div class="footer">
<img src="images/footer.png" width="239" height="15" /> 
</div><!-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------end of footer------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

Comment: also just to add. With my specific problem removing .mebg height:200px made it work how I wanted my side, as it created its own scroll cause of the background image being larger or something along those lines. But overall worked perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had to make a few adjustments but this was able to get it to have the green div over top of the red div and keep the footer at the bottom:

```
.contactwrapper{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.contact{
    float:left;
    background:#0F3;
    position: absolute;   /* .contact needs absolute positioning */
}
.mebg{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:#900;
    height:200px;
}
mebg img{
    width:30%;
}
.footer{
    z-index: 1;
    height: 30px;
    clear: both;       /* clear: both will bring the footer below the other divs */
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can move the comment div inside the red div `mebg`:

```
<div class="contactwrapper">
    <div class="mebg">
        <img src="images/contactnew.png" />
        <div class="contact">
             <p>please work</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------end of contact------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
<div class="footer">
<img src="images/footer.png" width="239" height="15" /> 
</div><!-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------end of footer------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

Add in `clear:both` as detailed in the other answer and this should work (or at least looks) like you want it to.

see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d78sdjm4/5/) for an example.

EDIT: I found this link on [CSS positioning](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) to be helpful. I think it explains things pretty clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `clear: both;` to `.footer { }` to get the black bar beneath the other two.
Also floating an element that has a width of 100% doesn't usually produce the desired results you're going for. It may be floated but since the width is 100% everything is pushed after it anyways.

Comment: okay great that fixed the footer problem. just the other problem being the other two divs

Comment: @factordog if you want a background image on a div why not use the `background-image:` in css? You won't need to use the `<img />` tag and text will always be above the image without floats.

Comment: its been giving me some major scaling problems, and its not a site i have been working on personally, I have been editing someones site to just get it ready quickly. This is the last bit I have to get working so just was hoping to find a quick fix to this problem

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already setting the `position` as `relative` for your `contactwrapper`, why not forego `float`s and just use `absolute` positioning?

Below is an example with your code as a base. Please note I removed a lot of styling that was unnecessary for the example.

```css
.contactwrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.contact {
  background: #0F3;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.mebg {
  background: #900;
  height: 200px;
}
.footer {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #000;
}

/* To look pretty: Hide overflow of the stock images */
.mebg,
.footer {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="contactwrapper">
  <div class="contact">
    <p>please work</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mebg">
    <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/700/200" />
  </div>
</div>
<!-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------end of contact------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
<div class="footer">
  <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/700/15" />
</div>
<!-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------end of footer------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

Comment: It wasn't clear how exactly you wanted the `contact` element to be centered. Here is another variation: http://jsfiddle.net/d78sdjm4/8/